# Hosting a website on a virtual private server with docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, web-hosting, vps

I need your help

I have some questions about hosting a containerized spring boot app on a virtual private server.
As we use docker for containerizing application in order to deliver it simply for testing and other purposes, but when we want to publish and deploy it on a VPS in the real world, should our containerized application (dockerized JAR file) run on the docker instead of a server like Tomcat (using WAR files)?

Briefly, can docker (installed on a VPS) be used as a web host for running our application? In other words, keep the docker running all the time like a web host to serve our web application?

Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, a Spring Boot (web) application is designed to run as a fat jar, as it contains an embedded Tomcat server by itself: [source](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications).

Comment: Yes that is right but what about docker? can we use it in production environment to run an application on a server and serve as a web host (keep the docker running all the time like a web host to serve our web application)?

Comment: @Pezhman, when docker installs on the machine/server, it runs as a daemon i.e. it will keep running all the time. Running application only in a container isn't recommend, you should use some orchestration tool (kubernetes or swarm) for production system.

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan, thank you, so I have to install kubernetes on my VPS or private server to manage containers?  am I right? do you know any resource about setting up and configuring kubernetes and docker on a private server (linux)?

Comment: @Pezhman you are making it too complex. If you are hosting all apps like db, frontend and backend on same server, and there is one server, using docker will be very complex. I would suggest using simple tomcat and deploy war. if you have multiple server and want to automate end to end, then I will suggest using docker and kubernetes

Comment: @Sridhar Patnaik, well I have created some microservice based applications. So because of the microservice nature they should be executed by docker and kubernetes . Have I any other choices to avoid complexity?

Comment: @Pezhman, installing kubernetes and managing it further is quite tedious and requires some infra as well as operational efforts. I would suggest you to go with managed services with different cloud providers. https://www.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan, that is right but not for me as an Iranian, unfortunately due to the sanctions nothing is accessible in Iran like AWS and the other services. thank you for your help